# Python print unique arrays from an array

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to print a unique set of arrays from an array **while keeping the array in order**.

Example array:

```
[[1,2,3], [1,3,2], [1,2,3], [3,1,2]]
```

The output that I am looking for is:

```
[[1,2,3], [1,3,2], [3,1,2]]
```

I've looked at converting the array into a set but it appears that it has issues with a 2D array (I believe it compares each element individually which if it could run, it would result in simply `[1,2,3]`) also, I am reading that it does not keep the order of the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need simple check if an element in the rest of your array and get rid of it. To preserve order, loop should go backwards:

```
array = [[1,2,3], [1,3,2], [1,2,3], [3,1,2]]

for a_ind in range((len(array)-1), 0, -1):
    if (array[a_ind] in array[:a_ind]):
        array.pop(a_ind)

print (array)
# [[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [3, 1, 2]]
```

Comment: Thanks mate! Appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Use a nested for-loop to see if an element has been seen already:

```
data = [[1,2,3], [1,3,2], [1,2,3], [3,1,2]]
processed = []
for i in range(len(data)):
    for j in range(i):
        if data[i] == data[j]:
            break
    else:
        processed.append(data[i])
print(processed)  # Should be [[1,2,3], [1,3,2], [3,1,2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
>>> u = [[1,2,3], [1,3,2], [1,2,3], [3,1,2]]
>>> unique = []
>>> (unique.append(x) for x in u if x not in unique)
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x103df4620>
>>> print(unique)
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [3, 1, 2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing for loops, you can:

```
class Foo(object):
  def __init__(self, a_list):
      self._list = list(a_list)
  def __str__(self):
      return str(self._list)
  def __repr__(self):
      return self.__str__()
  def __eq__(self, other):
      return all([i1 == i2 for i1, i2 in zip(self, other)])
  def __ne__(self, other):
      return any([i1 != i2 for i1, i2 in zip(self, other)])
  def __hash__(self):
      return 0
  def __iter__(self):
      return iter(self._list)

a1 = Foo([1, 2, 3])
a2 = Foo([1, 3, 2])
a3 = Foo([1, 2, 3])
a4 = Foo([3, 2, 1])
c = [a1, a2, a3, a4]
print(list(set(c)))

# Output
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [3, 2, 1]]
```

`__str__` and `__repr__` methods are for the output and `__iter__` for the list comprehension.

Online: https://repl.it/BqAS/0

Answer (score 0):

## Solution 1: using  dictionary to get rid of the lists that got the same elements

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [1, 2, 3], [3, 1, 2]]
d = {}

for k in a:
    d[str(k)] = k

a = []
for v in d.values():
    a += [v]

print(a)
```

> output*

[[1, 3, 2], [1, 2, 3], [3, 1, 2]]

- using a dictionary, this one can have the lists in the list in a different order each time you execute the script.

## Solution 2: looking into the list to pop the one that got the same order of elements

```
b = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [1, 2, 3], [3, 1, 2]]

for l in b:
    if l in b[b.index(l) + 1:]:
        b.pop(b.index(l))

print(b)
```

> output

[[1, 3, 2], [1, 2, 3], [3, 1, 2]]